# Where is the more appropriate place to open a db connection in a nuxt app and add it to api context?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, backend, nuxt3

I'm starting a new Nuxt 3 app. What I want to do is very simple: **I want to open a db connection when the server is started, and add it to the context object so that it's available to api handlers**; but I can't figure out where is the correct place to initialize a db connection. It should be a hook that a) runs when the server starts; b) has access to useRuntimeConfig(); and c) can add the connection object to the api route handlers' context object.

*Note: The examples that I have seen so far do it in a custoim nitro plugin, but they use libraries that store the connection in global variables (e.g. prisma and mongoose), so it doesn't work for me—nitro plugins are synchronous; and can't access the context object.*

Comment: `useAsyncData` + `useState`?

Comment: Composables like `useAsyncData` and `useState` run during render. You use them to make requests (in the client) or to call request handlers (in the server). The server must already be connected to the db at this point, to render the page.

Comment: from my understanding you want to run a function when `nuxt server` is started and tell nuxt to dump a chunk of data into `nuxt server` context (not `vue` context) right?

Comment: I want to run a function when nuxt server is started, yes, to connect to the db, but not to load data immediately, just to store the connection object itself (e.g. the `mongodb` object) into the api context (a.k.a. `event.context`; not vue context), so that it's available to request handlers (the functions inside `/server/api`, which handle `useFetch` and `useAsyncData`).

Comment: what you need is a plugin for the server: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-plugins

Comment: Unfortunately, nitro plugins don't have access to the context object.

Comment: you don't need to inject in `ctx` just it runs because `nuxt server` only run once then you just need to `import` it